# What is a Application under IIS site and when should we create it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, architecture, application-pool

I was reading about creating web sites to host on IIS and saw the "application" that is a folder which can run with different rules from the main site.

I'm just wondering where or when should we use these applications? There is something I'm not thinking about?

Maybe If I have an E-commerce application, and want to use the administration module outside the main module, what should I consider? Number of access? Permissions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: Hi @LexLi and thanks for your comment, I've already read this post a few days ago. It's from 2007 and I guess it could be considered ok yet, but the example on the documentation is too abstract to me. What are the advantages of isolate an app from another? How can we really use it? When should I consider it?

Comment: If you check the logic behind that articles, you should know that a site holds applications (even if you don't create an explicit one, there is already a root application). So whatever happens, you are already using applications. If your question is merely about isolation, that's been discussed in posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866534/asp-net-and-application-isolation

Comment: @LexLi thanks again! The another posts makes sense to me now! Maybe I missed the words and how to ask.